# String splitting/tokenizing in java without compiling a regex?

Tags: java, performance, code-formatting

Is there a short hand in the standard Java API that allows me to grab a token from a string `1^2^3^4` in 1 line? I want say the 3rd element "3" to be extracted. I do not want anything which compiles a regex. Having it passed in a precompiled regex is fine, but constantly compiling a regex every time a method is called hurts the CPU.

Comment: You mean you don't want to use String.split() because it has to use a pattern?

Comment: Could you show some code? I know it's what you are asking for, but are you completely sure there a harm to the CPU and you are not just prematurely optimizing?

Comment: @Gothmog Yes. The compiler will not optimize that (ie: compile the pattern and replace a reference with it) the last time I checked with Java 1.5 or 1.6. I'm assuming that is still the case. Using hprof, I have seen something as simple as a regex inside a method eat up a large percentage of cpu compute time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily split using a precompiled [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html);

```
static Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\^");

private static String getEntry(String input, int which)
{
    return regex.split(input)[which];
}
```

...or alternately, just do it in straight code instead of using a regex at all, since it won't create un-needed String objects, it should be faster.

```
private static String getEntry(String input, int which)
{
    int left, right = -1;
    do {
        left = right;
        right = input.indexOf('^', right+1);
    }
    while(which-- > 0 && right >= 0);

    if(which != -1)
        return null;

    if(right == -1)
        return input.substring(left+1);

    return input.substring(left+1, right);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compile a regex in Java using [`Pattern.compile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29), this will result in a `Pattern` object. You can re-use that object as often as you want, without having to compile the regex every time again. Just store the compiled pattern in a variable so you can retrieve it every time you need.

If you define a pattern that matches any number between `^`, you could create a `Matcher` object that matches your pattern against your input, using [`Pattern.matcher()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). The [`Matcher.group(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) method would give you access to a specific match in the given input.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Scanner class that lets you define a splitter character so you can call next() function until the element you want is found. There's no need for a regex to be used in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you're looking to avoid regular expressions entirely for perceived performance issues, you can try [Apache Commons StringUtils split()](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java) which does iterative processing. I haven't benchmarked it against the [Java standard library one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), but looking at the source I have a hard time imagining a significant performance difference.